# SPIN/JACKSON-JSON-01002 Expected ‘SpinList’, got ‘OBJECT’

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler, polyglot

I’m a bit new in Camunda.

I get an error when adding variable to idDcoumento from tasklist in http-connector in payload variable.

The inlined javascript is as follow:

```
var postJSONTemp = ‘{
“idUsuario”: "’+idUsuario+‘",
“idDocumento”: "’+idDocumento+‘",
“token”: "’+token+‘"
}’;
postJSONTemp;
```

The error i get is :

```
An error happened while submitting the task form : Cannot submit task form 39766db9-b5fd-11ee-bcf8-00090faa0001: Unable to evaluate script:org.camunda.spin.json.SpinJsonDataFormatException: SPIN/JACKSON-JSON-01002 Expected ‘SpinList’, got ‘OBJECT’
```

Appreciate any help.

I wanted to execute a script to pass a json in payload variable of http-connector in camunda modeler versión 7 but i go the error above